# What is the time complexity of this powerset function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, bit-manipulation, powerset

I solved this question (powerset function) from leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/submissions/ and here is my solution:

```
    def subsets(nums):
        res = []
        n = len(nums)
        for subset_id in range(2**n):
            tmp = []
            for index in range(n):
                if 1 << index > subset_id:
                    break
                if subset_id >> index & 1:
                    tmp.append(nums[index])
            res.append(tmp)
        return res
```

I am having a hard time analyzing the time complexity of this code, the statement `if 1 << index > subset_id: break` makes it under `O(n*2^n)` I think but does it take it all the way down to `O(2^n)` ?  I don't know it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that the inner loop is going to go through about half of `range(n)` before hitting the `break` every time, then this is `O(n/2*2^n)`, which is actually still `O(n*2^n)`. This works for any fixed fraction of the loop, so even if it's a tenth of `range(n)` on average instead of half, it's still `O(n*2^n)`